# Why is this JQUERY selector with a varibale and space not working?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

```
 $(".lookup "+id).css("background-color","green");
```

I want to to change the background of "lookup 123456" to green when matches are found. I write this to the console: console.log(".lookup "+id) it works fine. But it's not getting selected with the selector.

Any help?

Comment: what is id?? is it element id??

Comment: Its' a variable which contains the id - yes. The question has been answered below, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$("[class='lookup "+id+"']").css();
```

Comment: @PHPWhisperer it works because it selects based on the value of the class attribute of the elements, the reason why you are unable to use the class selector is because you can't have a space in a class name (what you have is two class names but the second is invalid since it starts with a number)

Comment: It will Work In your code its taking use space to select the child tag so when you use spaces directly it will go and check for lookup class. So we have to tell jQuery that this full class with space is name.

Comment: if it's not containg number this works because your looking for the attribute [class="lookup 78789789"] since your using a number as a class which is not allowed this works becuase it's not using the jquery default class finder..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not pretty clear about what you're looking for.

If you want to select elements with `class="lookup 123456"` then you should use `.` not `space`. Example:

```
$('.lookup.' + id);
```

If you want to select elements with `class="lookup" id="123456"` then you should use `#` not space. Example:

```
$('.lookup#' + id);
```

Your current selector is meaning select something like this.

```
<div class="lookup">
  <123456></123456>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am considering variable id holds id of element.

Assume id="something"

then if you use your code

```
 $(".lookup "+id).css("background-color","green");
```

is equal to

```
 $(".lookup something").css("background-color","green");
```

where something is not an element
there should be # to select by id.
so try this code

```
 $(".lookup #"+id).css("background-color","green");
```

This will be

```
 $(".lookup #something").css("background-color","green");
```

Answer (score 0):

A selector can not start with a number.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters

> In CSS, identifiers  (including
>   element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the
>   characters [a-z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the
>   hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);
>   they cannot start with a digit, or a
>   hyphen followed by a digit.
>   Identifiers can also contain escaped
>   characters and any ISO 10646 character
>   as a numeric code (see next item). For
>   instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be
>   written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)